# Weird Stuff in Terminal When I Hit Tab

Tags: command-line, bash

For some reason, today, everytime I hit tab in the terminal this shows up:

```
cat bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_CA)

Display all 150 possibilities? (y or n)
```

This particular one happens when I type `cat` then hit TAB. I never changed any setting or anything. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Does it still happen if you turn off the completion added by the bash-completion package for cat? `complete -r cat` and then `cat <TAB>` again.

Comment: well, first of all, please don't double post. I see you have also asked [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12501/weird-stuff-in-terminal-when-i-hit-tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console, type

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Select the locale that is relevant, and press spacebar. You will see an asterisk indicating the selected locale. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, to highlight OK. THen press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Same for the next screen. That should regenerate the environment locale for your installation of Ubuntu.